# How to paste over selected text in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublime-text-3

In Sublime Text 3, when I select something and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, the clipboard item is pasted after the selected item and does not replace it. How can I change this behavior to replace the selected item?

I have tried searching in the Default Prefs and Google to no avail.

Comment: Works as expected for me. Check your plugins.

Comment: Also try searching your _Key Bindings - Default_ and _Key Bindings - User_ (and any Key Bindings for installed packages) for `Ctrl + V` to make sure nothing is overriding the default behavior.

Comment: please provide the solution if you found it as I am also searching for one to no avail

Comment: @Raveren it's too old an issue :). if i remember it correctly, i believe it was caused by the clipboard manager i was using - some setting in that.

Comment: thanks, @Sudhanshu, that's not the case for me unfortunately